# How to find which textField has loaded the TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've a `ViewController` which two `UITextFields`. First text field is area name and when this text field is tapped it opens up (View displayed using [KGModal](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal)) a `UITableViewController` which sends call to server and fetch and display area names.
The second text field is dependent on the area text field. It's the zip code field and when user select the area and the tap on the zip code field it send a call with area name to fetch zip codes of that area.
My question is that how can I use the same table view controller class to send a different call based on the sender text field. I'm using [KGModal](https://github.com/kgn/KGModal) to display the view.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the delegate method of UITextField where I'm sending the `id` of the sender.

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

        if (textField==self.areaField) {
            [self.view endEditing:YES];
            [self showTableView:self.areaField];
            return NO;
        }
        else if (textField==self.zipField)
        {
            [self.view endEditing:YES];
            [self showTableView:self.zipField];
            return NO;
        }
        else return YES;
    }
```

And in the method I'm using it as

```
-(void)showTableView:(id)sender
{
    ServiceEnMTableViewController *ivc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CountryVC"];

    //ivc.delegate = self;

    ivc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]) - 40, CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]) - 80);
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] setCloseButtonType:KGModalCloseButtonTypeRight];
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] showWithContentViewController:ivc andAnimated:YES];
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] setTapOutsideToDismiss:YES];
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] setModalBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] setBackgroundDisplayStyle:KGModalBackgroundDisplayStyleSolid];
}
```

So how to pass the sender here?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You have a call back (`textFieldShouldBeginEditing`) that returns one of the 2 textfields, you check which textfield it is, but no matter what execute the same code. `showTableView ` now has no idea which textfield is which. Simply do as I said in my answer by passing `sender` into `showTableView` and check inside there which textfield it is, or change the param to a boolean and pass that in from the textfield callback

Comment: But `showTableView:(id)sender` is getting a value in the form of `(id)`. So based on that I've made a `@property (strong, nonnull) NSString *callFor;` in zip class where I'll pass the string value from area class and compare it in zip and will send the call. I can change the string to boolean to do the same. Is this what you are saying? Kindly code a little I might get more idea.

Comment: please see updated answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Enum like this.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, TextFieldsIdentifier) {
        kAreaField,
        kZipField,
    };
```

Now your textField Delegate will be look like this

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    if (textField==self.areaField) {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        [self showTableView:kAreaField];
        return NO;
    }
    else if (textField==self.zipField)
    {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
        [self showTableView:kZipField];
        return NO;
    }
    else return YES;
}
```

and your method `showTableView:` will look like this

```
-(void)showTableView:(TextFieldsIdentifier) textFieldIdentifier{
    ServiceEnMTableViewController *ivc = [self.storyboard      instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CountryVC"];
    //make property like @property(nonatomic,assign) TextFieldsIdentifier textFieldIdentifier; in ServiceEnMTableViewController and assign value
    ivc.textFieldIdentifier = textFieldIdentifier;
    //ivc.delegate = self;

    ivc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth([[UIScreen mainScreen]   bounds]) - 40, CGRectGetHeight([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]) - 80);
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] setCloseButtonType:KGModalCloseButtonTypeRight];
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] showWithContentViewController:ivc andAnimated:YES];
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] setTapOutsideToDismiss:YES];
    [[KGModal sharedInstance] setModalBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[KGModal sharedInstance]  setBackgroundDisplayStyle:KGModalBackgroundDisplayStyleSolid];
  }
```

Comment: how should I pass it to the next class? I mean KGModel is `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` so do I have to make a property in next class and pass it `kAreaField` or `kZipField`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Store an `IBOutlet` for each textfield.
2. When `textField DidBeginEditing` (or whatever else) is called, compare the `sender` param to the IBOutlets to find which one it is.
3. Now that you know which textfield it is, pass a parameter to the modal to indicate whether it should search for area names or zip codes.

**Update**

Try this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    [self showTableView:textField];
    return NO;
}

- (void)showTableView:(id)sender {
    if (sender == self.areaField) {
        // Tell tableView to load area data
    }
    else if (sender == self.zipField) {
        // Tell tableView to load zip data
    }
}
```

Comment: `[self showTableView:sender];` use of undeclared identifier 'sender'

Comment: @TalhaCh it was a typo, surely you noticed `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` has only 1 param???